# How to get a class file by Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, refresh, .class-file

I wrote an application in the Eclipse, which was successfully compiled and run. After that, in a corresponding directory I found  *.java and *.class files. Then I have deleted the *.class file and now I do not know how can I get it back.

Eclipse writes me "A class file was not written. The project may be inconsistent, if so try refreshing this project and building it".

By the right click on the project I got a drop down menu in which I found "Refresh" but I cannot find out how can I "build" the project.

So, how can I generate the class file again?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Cleaning the project should be enough to start the build. **Menu:Project ->Clean**
2. Check that automatic build is enabled. **Project -> Build Automatically**
3. If automatic build is disabled use build all. **Menu: Project -> Build All**

Comment: OK. But how can I "clean" the project?

Comment: If Build Automatically is disabled, the Clean dialog has an option (selected by default) to start a build after the clean anyway (at least in 3.4.x).

Comment: Ash, in my case the "Build Automatically" is not disabled. Should I disable it? Where can I find the clean dialog? How can I initiate the clean?

Comment: I found "Clean Up" in the "Source" menu. I clicked it and I did not get the desired *.class file.

Comment: "Clean..." is in the same "Project" menu as "Build Automatically".

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! Project->Clean worked well. Now I have the class-file.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error message when I have an inner class, and the total name of the main class and its inner classes exceeds 128 characters. This happens both on OpenJDK and Sun JDK 6. The solution for me was to shorten the inner class names.