# How do I get back my .class files?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying to connect to a database but in every debug session, I got an exception that my connection string wasn't valid. The exception showed me the old connection string which I had long changed to something else.

So, not knowing who was caching my old connection string, I guessed it must have been that Eclipse might be caching my old .class files and running them. So, I went to the `build` folder of my application and deleted all my class files for my project. These were class files made out of my source.

Then, I build the project again. But the class files do not appear back again.

Now, when I try to Debug the application, it complains about not finding the missing class files.

What do I do to build the class files afresh?

I am using Eclipse for Java EE, Mars 2.

Comment: Eclipse => Project => Build All

Comment: You can refer to below link to generate .class files. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280176/how-to-get-a-class-file-by-eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280176/how-to-get-a-class-file-by-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you. But when I either `Build Project` or `Build Working set` (after adding this project and its related ones to a working set) or `Build All`, nothing happens. The console window is also rather quiet. There's no action at all.

Comment: Okay, I have *no idea what happened* but after trying for several times, I see the class files are back now again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Clean the project: `Project|clean`
2. Rebuild the project: `Build All`.

Comment: If you want to post something as an answer, please provide more information/details. For instance: why do it like this? what does this do that 'build all' itself doesn't? ..

Comment: @Stultuske It's true that he should have read [answer] first, but this answer is sufficient in this case. It would be much better if there was some explanation how clean or build work, but the user still have much time to learn

Comment: @Stultuske@xenteros Ok. Thank you for both of your advise.